# I am trying to add followers & following properties inside a custom struct to my User object that is conforming to the Identifiable/decodable protocal

Tags: swift, firebase

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

import Firebase
```

// I created this object so that i can map the users data and access it threw this object. example I could say thigs like user.username
// The decodable protocall will read the data dictonary and looks for the exact name for the keys/property names I have listed in the data dictonary, this makes life easier when working with objects and downloading information from an api

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
```

// Im able to delete the uid field out of firebase because this will read the documentID from firebase and store it in this id property, so that I dont have to dupicate that data in the actual body of the object

```
@DocumentID var id: String?

let username: String

let fullname: String

let profileImageUrl: String

let email: String



let stats: UserStats



// This is a computed property saying if the currently logged in user's id is equal      to the id on my object (@DocumentID) 

var isCurrentUser: Bool { return Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == id }


  }

struct UserStats: Decodable {

let followers: Int


let following: Int

}
```

Comment: every time I trying to add the custom struct to my user object I don't get an error but my app loads without any of my users that I have inside my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `?` at the end of each variable.

`@FirestoreQuery` does little error handling when it comes to decoding.

Also, if you are not using `@FirestoreQuery` use `do try catch` instead of `try?`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro the, adding the ? to the end of each variable solved the problem.

Comment: @whoolee im glad it helped. Do you mind marking this as the answer? It is the green check mark above.

Comment: got you bro, this my first time using stack lol.